# cant able to import csv file to mongodb database 2.4.9.

Tags: mongodb, csv

I tried many ways in importing the csv file into mongodb. But all were throwing me errors. My Import command which i tried is

```
mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1:270107 -d test -c test --type csv --file d:\sakthi\mcmis\ktest.csv --headerline

Error: Couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1:270107] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:270107.
```

Then i tried without using the host(--host). At That time the error was "Couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:270107."

1. I tried to run this mongoimport command in command prompt only not in the Mongo shell
2. I tried to run this command several times in both scenarios, after running the mongod command and then after closing the mongod command also. In both the cases, it was throwing the same error.
3. When the mongod is running, I can able to acces localhost:28017 too.

Help me out to sort out this issue :( ...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is your database running?  i.e, have you started mongod? and it looks like you got your port number wrong.. mongod runs on 27017 by default.. not 270107

Comment: Definitely the wrong port number. Port numbers can't be higher than 65535. The default is 27017. :)

Comment: thanks @AnandJayabalan. It was my mistake in specifying the port number wrongly. And one more doubt I have. when i'm trying to import the file from some location "Multiple occurrence" error is occurring. But its importing when i'm having the file inside mongodb bin folder.

Comment: When my folders have some name with space, its showing that "Multiple occurrence error" in that case only. Like c:\new folder\test.csv . If I change the folder name without space "newfolder" like this "c:\newfolder\test.csv" then the import is happening without any error.

Comment: You should post a new question, as this is unrelated to your original question.